# Developing webpage with Webiopi on a raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raspberry-pi, webiopi

I'm a noob and new to web-development and i'm overwhelmed with the multitude of languages. I got the basic understanding on whats going on but I still don't know where I am getting stuck.

I have a DS18B20 connected to my  Raspberry Pi and I am able to fetch the temperature in the terminal. I am running the WebIOPi successfully as well and able to see the temperature in its default web page under Devices. So I was hoping to create my own web page that would do the exact same thing with other options for future. I got a hold of some tutorials on WebIOPi and i got 4 files. An HTML file, the JavaScript file, the CSS file and a Python file. In my understanding the HTML file contains the logic and links to other things like clickable buttons and backgrounds etc. The CSS file contains the background and maybe text, the JavaScript file contains animation and buttons? Here I get confused. Last but not least the Python file is what runs the code that contains sensor model and libraries. I configured the Webiopi config file with my sensors serial number as mentioned here: http://webiopi.trouch.com/OneWireTemp.html. I am loosely trying to follow this tutorial where I got most parts of the code: http://webiopi.trouch.com/Tutorial_Devices.html.

Now when I log into the webpage from my browser the background is displayed correctly, but nothing else. There is no box or button showing the temperature. Pictures are attached. I was hoping for a button like attached in the picture.

Any guidance or help would be appreciated!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WebIOPi | UNB Temperature</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bacon.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/bacon.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
// declare few global variables
var tmp;

webiopi().ready(init);

// defines function passed to webiopi().ready()
function init() {
    // setup helpers to remotely control devices
    tmp = new Temperature("tmp");
    // automatically refresh UI each seconds
    setInterval(updateUI, 1000);
}

// function called through setInterval
function updateUI() {
    // call Temperature.getCelsius REST API
    // result is asynchronously displayed using the callback
    tmp.getCelsius(temperatureCallback);

}    

// callback function used to display the temperature
function temperatureCallback(sensorName, data) {
    // jQuery functions
    $("#bt_heater").text(data + "°C");
}
```

bacon.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div align="center">
<button id="bt_mode" onclick="toggleMode()"/><br>
    <button id="bt_heater" onclick="toggleHeater()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

bacon.css

```
body { 
background-color:#000000;
background-image:url('/img/wall.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;

}
```

script.py

```
import webiopi
GPIO = webiopi.GPIO
AUTO = True
def loop():
if (AUTO):
    tmpwebiopi.deviceInstance("tmp")
    celsius = tmp.getCelsius()
    print ("Temperature: %f" % celsius)
    webiopi.sleep(1)
```

[image: This image is the original webpage that WebioPi runs and I am able to view the temperature here without any issue]

[image: My website background I made and it shows in the browser but not other information shows like textbox or button with any temperature readings!]

[image: I was hoping for something like this to appear as I used similar code]

Comment: Could you please reduce your question to a minmum example? All these images clutter the question, make it less clear and contribute little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about your specific case, but to me it seems quite obvious that there is nothing to see here. You have been mixing up things quite a bit.

To clarify things

- The HTML contains the logical structure of your website
- the CSS contains the look and feel (design)
- the JavaScript and the Python files contain (UI)-Logic

This is quite coarse and might deviate, but it should suffice as a start and should apply here.

The obvious errors in your code

- The HTML file is incomplete. It should not stop in the middle of the `script`-section, there should be markup defining the buttons you want to display. Currently there is none, hence there is nothing to see (but the HTMl-body, which is added automatically - and since the background color is defined for the body it is displayed)
- The JavaScript file does not actually contain JavaScript, but HTML, which is most likely not correct
- At the moment all your JavaScript is located within the script-section of your HTML file. This is fine as long as your are just trying to work it out, but renders a separate JS-file useless at the moment.

All in all your HTML file should look more like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WebIOPi | UNB Temperature</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bacon.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/bacon.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
// declare few global variables
var tmp;

webiopi().ready(init);

// defines function passed to webiopi().ready()
function init() {
    // setup helpers to remotely control devices
    tmp = new Temperature("tmp");
    // automatically refresh UI each seconds
    setInterval(updateUI, 1000);
}

// function called through setInterval
function updateUI() {
    // call Temperature.getCelsius REST API
    // result is asynchronously displayed using the callback
    tmp.getCelsius(temperatureCallback);

}    

// callback function used to display the temperature
function temperatureCallback(sensorName, data) {
    // jQuery functions
    $("#bt_heater").text(data + "°C");
}
</script></head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<button id="bt_mode" onclick="toggleMode()"/><br>
    <button id="bt_heater" onclick="toggleHeater()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay it worked! I got rid of the entire java script file since I understood from your explanation that I already have the python code which is fetching the temperature from the appropriate sensor. I updated the HTML file like you suggested and got the web page to show a small box with the temperature reading inside! My only question to you is how do I reposition the text that is being displayed in the box as well as how do I reposition the box as well? Does this have to be done in the HTML file or the CSS file? My CSS file only contains information about the background. Again Thanks a Bunch!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please do not forget to mark my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: I marked you question correct! You guided me to the right path, Could you perhaps let me know which file I should be working to correct the placement of the temperature and the box it self? You can have a look at the picture I attach in the revised answer post.

Answer (score 0):

My Current code that is WORKING but with minor style problems.

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WebIOPi | UNB Temperature</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/bacon.css">



<script type="text/javascript">

// declare few global variables
var tmp;

webiopi().ready(init);

// defines function passed to webiopi().ready()
function init() {
    // setup helpers to remotely control devices
    tmp = new Temperature("tmp");
    // automatically refresh UI each seconds
    setInterval(updateUI, 1000);
}

// function called through setInterval
function updateUI() {
    // call Temperature.getCelsius REST API
    // result is asynchronously displayed using the callback
    tmp.getCelsius(temperatureCallback);

}    

// callback function used to display the temperature
function temperatureCallback(sensorName, data) {
    // jQuery functions
    $("#temp_disp").text(data + "°C");
}
 </script></head>
 <body>
 <div align="center">

    <button id="temp_disp" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.CSS

```
body { 
background-color:#000000;
background-image:url('/img/wall.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;

}
```

Current view of the webpage!

[image: Current view of the webpage]